# Call stored procedure to input data in database from ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I want to insert the data from ASP.NET Web API to my data in SQL Server in pre defined table. First I am getting response after calling REST API and want to insert the response in table in database.

API Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOutput(int id)
{
    string CheckJob = "exec sp_GetJob "+ "@id= " + id;

    var result = _context.Job.FromSqlRaw(CheckJob).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    if(result == null){
        string InsertResult = "exec sp_add" + "@result = " + result;
        _context.FromSqlRaw(InsertResult);  <-- Don't know how to call stored procedure
    }

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Stored Procedure

```
create procedure sp_add @result int
as
begin 
    insert into School(id, created_date)
        values (@result, GetDate());
end
```

I am facing issue in calling stored procedure to insert data. Can somebody please help me out?

Thank you

Comment: Your Web API won't be using SSMS - thats purely a client UI.

Comment: What is your `_context`? Entity Framework?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of examples of how to do this out there. What resources have you checked out? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DaleK Yes _context I tried using Entity Framework. But I know it is not correct implementation.

Comment: @DaleK I know how to call stored procedure to get data from database. But I don't know how to call stored procedure to insert data

Comment: Are you or are you not using EF? It's kinda important

Comment: Calling an sp is  pretty much the same regardless of whether it returns data. You just don't get anything back

Comment: If I don't want to use EF, then how to do ?

Comment: You need to first decide you method of data access and then ask your question. All data access frameworks support stored procedures.

Comment: `FromSqlRaw` is for results. Your procedure returns no results so you want `ExecuteSqlRaw` instead, also you should parameterize properly `_context.Job.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec sp_GetJob @id = {0}", id);`  note that the string is *not* a `$` format string

Comment: It is fine to use EF for this, just use the Database Facade (`_context.Database`). This would either be `ExecuteSqlRaw` as above, although my preference is to use an interpolated string, i.e. `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"exec sp_GetJob @id = {id}");`, having the variable name within the string itself makes it marginally more readable to me than using `{0}, {1}` as place holders and adding all the variables at the end. Finally, I'd [advise against prefixing your stored procedures with `sp_`](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you dont expect any data to return, try this

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(result);
```

or async with params

```
var resultParam = new SqlParameter("@result", result);
await   context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC  sp_add @result", resultParam);
```

Comment: my intelligence is not showing ExecuteSqlCommand